# How can we use chrome debugger mode for testing screen size of Microsoft Surface Pro 4?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, size, screen

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET and I am using chrome browser for testing it. My clients are using Microsoft Surface 4 Pro and I want to test my application on that screen using Chrome Debugger but I am unable to add a screen size for it in my chrome browser. Is there any way in which I can add the screen size in chrome browser so that I can test it before rolling out to the clients?

Answer (score 1):

Press F12 in chrome to go DevTools and there is an option for device mode

[image]

You can then add your custom resolution:

[image]

Microsft Surface Pro has a resolution = 2736x1824